# How can I use 'self' in Python decorators inside class?

Tags: python

If I run this fragment of Python code:

```
from telebot import TeleBot

class QuizBot:

    def __init__(self, TOKEN: str) -> None:
        self.bot: TeleBot = TeleBot(TOKEN)

    @self.bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
    def authorization(self, message): 
        self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "TEST")
    
    def run(self):
        print("[+] Bot is started.")
        self.bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

I receive the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Yudzhyn\Documents\MyStudy\Programming\Python\My\quiz_bot\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bot import QuizBot
  File "C:\Users\Yudzhyn\Documents\MyStudy\Programming\Python\My\quiz_bot\bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    class QuizBot:
  File "C:\Users\Yudzhyn\Documents\MyStudy\Programming\Python\My\quiz_bot\bot.py", line 8, in QuizBot
    @self.bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

How can it possible to fix?

Comment: The decorator is invoked when the class object is being created. At that point, the class isn't fully created, so there _definitely_ can't be any instances of it that `self` would refer to.

Comment: You cannot with the current design. The method lives in a broader scope than the instance attribute. You would have to "decorate" the method inside `__init__` or move the Telebot to global scope. Why do you use a class for this to begin with? Do you intend to create multiple instances?

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is just a function so we can use it as such in some other place instead.

Try this:

```py
from telebot import TeleBot

class QuizBot:

    def __init__(self, TOKEN: str) -> None:
        self.bot: TeleBot = TeleBot(TOKEN)
        self.authorization = self.bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])(self.authorization)

    def authorization(self, message):
        self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "TEST")

    def run(self):
        print("[+] Bot is started.")
        self.bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```